# How do I create a new categorical variable from continuous multiple observations?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tapply

This is my data:

```
ID  dist
1   23
1   10
2   12
2   20
3   14
3   33
```

I want to go through each ID, and create a new column ("state") for the larger value for each ID call it "high" and for the lower value, call it "low".

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R base

```
> transform(df1, state = ave(dist, ID, FUN= function(x)ifelse(x==max(x), "high", "low")))

  ID dist state
1  1   23  high
2  1   10   low
3  2   12   low
4  2   20  high
5  3   14   low
6  3   33  high
```

Comment: If it is inside `transform`, you don't need the `df1$`  Could be made a bit more compact ith `transform(df1, state = c('low', 'high')[(ave(dist, ID, FUN = max) == dist) + 1])`

Answer (score 1):

We can create a condition with `max/min`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(state = case_when(dist == max(dist) ~  "high",
                           dist == min(dist) ~ "low",
                           TRUE  ~ NA_character_))
```

As there are two values per each 'ID', the second condition is not needed

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(state = case_when(dist == max(dist) ~  "high",
                         TRUE  ~"low"))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), dist = c(23L, 
10L, 12L, 20L, 14L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[order(ID, dist), v := c("lo", "hi")]

   ID dist  v
1:  1   23 hi
2:  1   10 lo
3:  2   12 lo
4:  2   20 hi
5:  3   14 lo
6:  3   33 hi
```